# In Powerbuilder .Net, how do I set a constant UUID (GUID) for my assembly?

Tags: .net, powerbuilder

I want to rebuild my assembly with an updated version number, but updating the version number will cause the assembly to be rebuilt with a new UUID.  I want to prevent the UUID from being updated so the assembly can be dropped in at the customer site without having to do any additional steps related to the registry.  Is there a way to specify a constant UUID in Powerbuilder .Net that will always be used?

Thanks

Comment: If all else fails (and I hope it does not) ildsam ; fix bug ; ilasm.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but unfortunately it did not work.  Very interesting stuff though.  Actually, it turns out that what I'm trying to do probably wont accomplish what I want.  Even if the ID is kept constant, the version number will still have changed which will require action to be taken to update those values.

Comment: Having been down this path, I can say that it is possible to change the code any way you want w/o changing version number or assembly GUID. The only limit is your patience. This technique is slow, and you need to be able to read assembly to do it.